# Error message related to "onClick"

Tags: android

I try to make a simple project which save words in the sdcard and load it on the textView but stuck with the error below.

Anyone, how to solve the problem ??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
EditText editText2;
TextView textView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)   findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

}

public void onButton1Clicked(View v) {
    String input = editText.getText().toString();

    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + input;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Filename : " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String contents = editText2.getText().toString();
    writeToFile(filename, contents);
}

public void onButton2Clicked(View v) {
    String input = editText.getText().toString();
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + input;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Filename : " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    readFromFile(filename);
}

public void writeToFile(String filename, String contents) {

    File file = new File(filename);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);

        outStream.writeUTF(contents);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void readFromFile(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);

    try {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream instream = new DataInputStream(fileStream);

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int count = instream.read(data, 0, 1024);
        String line = new String(data, 0, count, "UTF8");

        textView.setText(line);
        instream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

=======================================

## Error Message

05-23 12:04:44.421 27478-27478/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: truevision.com.myapplication, PID: 27478
                                                   **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick**
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                    **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)**
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815) 
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                    **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                       at truevision.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onButton1Clicked(MainActivity.java:58)**
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815) 
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: A side note : when you're declaring the 2nd editText on onCreate you just replace the first editText

Comment: post your related layout xml

Comment: i think it's naming problem in onClick check your xml file

Comment: `String contents = editText2.getText().toString();`

you are using editText but you have not initialized it above

`editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);'
  
it should be 

`editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);`

Answer (score 1):

```
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    TextView textView;

     editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
     // here is issue editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: however, there is no error signs like red line or something on teh android studio...

Comment: its not a syntax error ....its produce at runtime. is your problem fixed.